# How do I use global variables in HTML/Javascript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following setting:
My Raspberry Pi is connected to a display. The Raspberry Pi shows a HTML-Webpage with a RSS Newsfeed. The Raspberry Pi also hosts a Configuration Web-page

The HTML that shows the RSS looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FeedEk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed=function(){
      $('#divRss').FeedEk({
        **FeedUrl: 'http://www.tagesschau.de/xml/rss2'**,
        MaxCount: 5,
        ShowDesc: true,
        ShowPubDate: true,
        DescCharacterLimit: 100,
        DateFormat: 'L',
        DateFormatLang: 'en'
      });
    ;}

feed();

setInterval(feed, 10*60*1000);

</script>

<div id="divRss"></div>
```

The Variable `FeedUrl` is currently hard coded and decides which RSS-Feed to be shown.

Now **I want to have** a config-file with the `FeedUrl`.

The Configuration Webpage should write the `FeedUrl` in the config-file.
And the HTML should read the `FeedUrl` from the config-file. As you can see I dont know which file format the config file should be.

[image: Current Situation]

The Config-Webpage should be like this. When you click the button the URL should be saved in the config-file

```
<form>
<label for="URL">URL: </label>
<input type="text" id="FeedURL" name="URL">

<button type="submit">SAVE!"</button>
</form>
```

=> So my Questions are:
1. Which file format do I need to save and extract information?
2. How can I write information in the file?
3. How do I read the informations from the file?

Comment: Have you had a look at *php read config file* , *php echo* ?

Comment: You just need some server side code to make this happen. Since all you're storing is a url, you can create a text file to hold the value. Add a form and handle it in PHP. Use PHP to write the value to the text file when the form gets submitted and load the value on each request.

Comment: I am not so familiar with php could you help me a little bit how to do this?

Comment: Consider writing to json and using ajax to retrieve the json in your html page. Or you need to convert html file to php file and write stored url in that file. Can also run node.js on server